# FoxPro Provider For Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foxpro

How Can I Work with Fox pro DataBase With Entity Framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334930/linq-with-foxpro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must, use the OleDB .Net driver with the FoxPro ODBC driver. Don't blame me if performance is poor though.

Comment: Can you please add links and a small sample to you answer?

Answer (score 4):

Last year I spent a fair amount of time trying to develop a VFP EF Provider.  I was able hook into the designer and get basic queries working.  But this year other interests have prevented me from completing the project.  I’m going to post my code on [codeplex](http://vfpefprovider.codeplex.com/) to see if I can get some development help in wrapping up this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use EF with FoxPro because there is no EF enabled provider available.

You can use OBDC or OLEDB but then you need to write you own data layer.